# PHP Function Returning True When It Should Return False

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with a PHP function for a very small WYSIWIG-like app. The following function determines whether a user owns a page. It has print statement for debugging.

```
function is_owned($sitename, $page_id)
{
    $output = false;

    $result = count(single_row_query(sprintf("SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE sitename='%s' AND page_id='%s';", addslashes($sitename), addslashes(strval($page_id)))));

    print $result;

    if ($result != 0)
        {$output = true; }

    return $output;
}
```

The following is the output of the page I'm using to debug the function.

```
SELECT sitename FROM session WHERE uid='l8rc8ssri8qr65lqvtfp174s91'
SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE sitename='Test' AND page_id='132432';
Result: 0
The function has returned true.
```

As you can see, the value of $result is 0, but the function still returned true. The SQL statements are included, though the problem doesn't seem to lie there.

The following function is called be the is_owned(), but is not likely to be relevant, as it seems to be functional.

```
function single_row_query($query)
{
    $database_connection = open_connection();

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $output = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $output = $output[0];

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($database_connection);

    return $output;
}
```

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Edit: Additionally, this is the output of the test page when it is supposed to return true:

```
! SELECT sitename FROM session WHERE uid='l8rc8ssri8qr65lqvtfp174s91' !
! SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE sitename='Test' AND page_id='7'; !
Result: 1
The function has returned true.
```

Comment: Could you include the code that prints 'The function has returned true'? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Oh, derp. You're completely correct, I forgot to put a $ on a variable. Sorry for the trivial question.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was the result of a typo, but here is why the other answers are completely wrong.

PHP [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) *always returns an int*.  Specifically:

> Returns the number of elements in var. If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Regardless of what else happens in the `single_row_query` function, `count` will return an int.  At that point, there is no practical difference between `$result != 0` and `$result !== 0` or the other posited issues.  Strong type comparison doesn't matter because you will necessarily be comparing an int value with an int value.

At that point, your function was sound and your problem must reside somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if ($result !== 0) {
    $output = true;
}
```

Comment: It is still returning true when $result is 0.

Answer (score -1):

Try this condition [UPDATED]

```
if(!empty($result))
{$output = true; }
```

Comment: The function doesn't have access to the SQL result, its handled by another function. The $result variable is the first (and only) row of the SQL result.

Answer (score -2):

1. make `var_dump($result)` instead of `print $result` in cause of var_dump prints type of variable (print converts variable to string), so you will see real value.
2. use `if ($result !== 0)` for strong type comparison.